Cannot verify bitcoin core 28.0
I have completed all the steps from 0 to 9, but at step 10 when i try to verify it by doing
gpg.exe --verify SHA256SUMS.asc
i receive the response as
gpg: no signed data gpg: can't hash datafile: No data

Where do you find these steps?

Most likely OP is talking about the steps from the Windows verification instructions at https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/

It sounds like you might be missing the checksum file or signature files. Are you sure that all of the prior steps succeeded? Maybe try to go through it again and take another look at the responses for each of the steps to make sure that everything was in the right folders and nothing returned an unexpected error.
If it still does not work, please provide some information on the step that failed or other information that might help potential responders to get a sense of where the problem might be.
